# Convert String Array into table format?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I got these arrays:

```
        String[] s0={"A","A","B","B","A","C"};

        String[] s11={"A","30"};
        String[] s12={"B","20"};
        List<String[]> l1=new ArrayList<String[]>();
        l1.add(s11);
        l1.add(s12);

        String[] s21={"B","10"};
        String[] s22={"B","20"};
        List<String[]> l2=new ArrayList<String[]>();
        l2.add(s21);
        l2.add(s22);

        String[] s31={"C","2"};
        String[] s32={"A","10"};
        String[] s33={"A","3"};
        List<String[]> l3=new ArrayList<String[]>();
        l3.add(s31);
        l3.add(s32);
        l3.add(s33);

        //result:
        String[] s1={"A","30","","10"};
        String[] s2={"A","","","3"};
        String[] s3={"B","20","10",""};
        String[] s4={"B","","20",""};
        String[] s5={"A","","",""};
        String[] s6={"C","","","2"};
```

The result should have 6 String Array, each String array should have 4 string corresponding to 4 columns:
This is very tough,do u know how to do?

Comment: Why dont try 2d array?

Comment: You can use `String.format("%-10s", yourStringAsParameter)` in order to print the `String` in a 10 space block and left aligned.

Comment: The task here is to bring all the String Array s0,s11,s12,s21,s22,s31,s32,s33 into s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6
This is very tough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the array s0 as your list for entries to the table (first column of Row), iterate each of them in the order. Your other 3 column values for each entry of s0 would be the value s0 element at Nth occurrence from among the Arrays in the lists. If there is no element at Nth occurrence then consider "" for column value. Every row formed would be an Array again with all column's values. You need to maintain the order of Arrays in List l1,l2 and l3. This is high-level logic to implement your requirement. Hope this would help.